# My React component renders before the props data is available using hooks

Tags: reactjs

So I'm creating a simple tile matching app.
I have a tile component that is fed props from a game board component that houses the tiles and that itself is within the app obviously that has the main logic and there state data.

I need each Tile to have its own logic to know if it should be flipped or not.

The problem I have encountered is that when I create a state data for which tiles are flipped and/or should stay flipped the tiles are running their component level logic with previous render data.

This means I match two tiles, these are added to relevant state - selectedTiles and matchedTiles which is passed to the all the tiles. The tiles check if there are two values in selectedTiles and if so to then check matchedTiles to see if that value matches a component level prop.
however the logic to check matchedTiles, which is triggered by selectedTiles changing, runs before the matchedTiles prop reaches the component.

I understand that this is because of the snapshot of the state but I'm unsure how to actually solve the problem.

apologies for any misunderstanding or explaining as this is my first fully self written react app.

I have linked the repository on git below.

https://github.com/Samuel-Programmer/React-Tiles

Comment: try to share the relevant code in here, you're not likely to find help if someone needs to debug you entire app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pulled you repo and changed the code a little bit.

In my opinion, it is better to hold 2 separate variables with useState, one for the opened tile and one for the 2nd 'guess'.

I also added a setTimeout to hide both open tiles after 1 second, in case they do not match.

I added an 'awaitingFlip' variable to prevent the user from flipping more tiles while the 2 last tiles have not been flipped back on a wrong guess.

Passing all the information in each tile is bad coding. The app gets slower, since react has to calculate more stuff. I added a prop 'isFlipped' to each tile, which is true in case two tiles have been matched or a tile has been checked as a first or second guess.

I also added a 'tileId' property to each tile, because I do not like working with indexes as ids.

I changed the unsplash search from 'south africa' to 'patagonia', 'cause I was getting a duplicate image which was frustrating. I advise you to hide your unsplash api key from the repo and generate a new one, as people will be able to use it.

You should be able to do the rest of the work (like 'play again', 'reshuffle', etc...).

I hope I helped. If you need any more help, leave a comment.

Here's the code (the files I do not include are the same):

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import unsplash from "../api/unsplash";
import Header from "./Header";
import GameBoard from "./GameBoard";

function App() {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("patagonia");
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [randomisedImages, setRandomisedImages] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    randomiseImages(images);
  }, [images]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getImages();
  }, [searchTerm]);
 
  const generateTileId = () => {
    return 'tile_id_' + Math.random().toString().substr(2, 8);
  }

  const getImages = async () => {
    const response = await unsplash.get("/search/photos", {
      params: { query: searchTerm },
    });
    setImages(response.data.results);
  };

  const randomiseImages = (images) => {
    let randomizedImages = [...images, ...images];
    
    var m = images.length,
      t,
      i;
    while (m) {
      i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
      t = randomizedImages[m];
      randomizedImages[m] = randomizedImages[i];
      randomizedImages[i] = t;
    }

    let finalArray = [];
    for (let x of randomizedImages) {
      finalArray.push({
        ...x,
        tileId: generateTileId()
      })
    }
    
    setRandomisedImages([...finalArray]);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Container>
        <Header />
        <Main>
          <GameBoard images={randomisedImages} />
        </Main>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

const Container = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 7rem;
`;

const Main = styled.div`
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
`;
```

GameBoard.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

import Tile from "./Tile";

function GameBoard({ images }) {
  const [selectedTile, setSelectedTile] = useState(null);
  const [secondTile, setSecondTile] = useState(null);
  const [matchedTiles, setMatchedTiles] = useState([]);
  const [awaitingFlip, setAwaitingFlip] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (matchedTiles.length > 0 && matchedTiles.length === images.length / 2) {
      alert('YOU WON!!! :)');
    }
  }, [matchedTiles])

  const onTileClick = (tileId, id) => {
    if (!matchedTiles.includes(id) && tileId !== selectedTile && !awaitingFlip) {
      
      let subjectId = images.find(x => x.tileId === selectedTile)?.id;
      
      if (!selectedTile) {
        setSelectedTile(tileId);
      } else {
        if (id === subjectId) {
          setMatchedTiles([...matchedTiles, id]);
          setSelectedTile(null);
        } else {
          setSecondTile(tileId);
          setAwaitingFlip(true);
          setTimeout(() => {
            setSecondTile(null);
            setSelectedTile(null);
            setAwaitingFlip(false);
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return (
    <TileContainer>
      {images.length > 1 &&
        images.map(({ description, urls, id, tileId }, index) => (
          <Tile
            key={index}
            id={id}
            tileId={tileId}
            alt={description}
            src={urls.regular}
            onTileClick={onTileClick}
            isFlipped={selectedTile === tileId || secondTile === tileId || matchedTiles.includes(id)}
          />
        ))}
    </TileContainer>
  );
}

export default GameBoard;

const TileContainer = styled.div`
  background: black;
  padding: 7rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;
```

Tile.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import tile from "./tile.jpeg";
import styled from "styled-components";

function Tile({ id, alt, src, onTileClick, tileId, isFlipped }) {

  return (
    <Imgcontainer onClick={() => onTileClick(tileId, id)}>
      <img alt={alt} src={isFlipped ? src : tile} id={id} />
    </Imgcontainer>
  );
}

export default Tile;

const Imgcontainer = styled.div`
  height: 10rem;
  width: 10rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 10%;
  cursor: pointer;

  img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10%;
  }
  img:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 15px #dcfffe;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10%;
  }
`;
```

Comment: Hey! thanks so much. I'm keen to look at the work you've done and build what you've achieved myself. That makes so much sense to not give the individual tiles so much data as also it helps with the original issue by keeping the game logic all in one place then passing as props. I'm currently looking through your code and understanding how what you've done works. would It be cheeky of me to ask how the rest of my code is in relation to best practice using react? I've been learning from a few tutorials and am now setting out to build some projects to get my practical understanding up. Thanks!

Comment: Also what does the question mark here do? let subjectId = images.find(x => x.tileId === selectedTile)?.id;

Comment: In my experience, you will learn to apply the best practices by... practicing!

1. You should keep the 'core state' of the app as 'high' as possible. See more about state and 'lifting state up' in the official React.js docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: 2. As for the question mark, it is plain javascript. Array.prototype.find() returns the first element of an array that matches a statement. Here we want to find a tile. There are 2 cases: 1. we find the tile and 2. we do not find it. The question mark makes sure the app won't crash if we ask for the id (or some other element) of an undefined element.

Take this for example:

let x = { id: 5 };
let y;
console.log(x.id); // prints 5
console.log(y?.id); // prints undefined
console.log(y.id); // throws error

Feel free to ask any other questions you want. Wish you the best!

Comment: Thanks, I do plan to keep practicing haha yeah I hate the idea of getting confident in what i'm doing then to find I've been doing things wrong etc. I guess I just need to keep going and look at other peoples code as well and seek out good examples. And yes I figured it out that it was just plain javascript by omitting the ? and understanding it was another way of conditional rendering. I had just never seen it in such a way before!